# How to Convert Object to Array of Objects - TypeScript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

var car =  {model: 'Rav4', Brand: 'Tayota'}

I want this to converted to [{model: 'Rav4', Brand: 'Tayota'}]

Answer (score 0):

var table = [].concat(car);

//Now **table** will be an array of the object **car** 
// [{model: 'Rav4', Brand: 'Tayota'}] 
//this is useful at times when you are not sure if you are getting array of objects or just the object.

Comment: Did that answer work for you?  It should be a typescript error since `[]` has type `never[]`.

Comment: You want `const table = [car]` which creates an array of car-type objects.  I'm sure this question can be closed as a duplicate.